# Understanding typecasting(pointers)

Tags: c++, c

I am reading the Beej's Guide to network programming book and I am having trouble understanding a function. The function expects a `char *` pointer but it dereferences the pointer and casts it to a (unsigned long int) and perform some bitwise operations. Why couldn't we just pass it as a 
`(unsigned int *)` instead of `(unsigned char *)`. Also if the parameter was replaced by `(void *)` and then inside code we did some thing like:

```
*(unsigned long int *)buf[0] << 24
```

will we get the same result? (Sorry this is my first time asking a question here so let me know if any more info is required).

```
unsigned long int unpacku32(unsigned char *buf)
{
    return ((unsigned long int)buf[0]<<24) |
           ((unsigned long int)buf[1]<<16) |
           ((unsigned long int)buf[2]<< 8) |
                               buf[3];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're suggesting is not guaranteed to work.  Unless `buf` points to an actual `unsigned long`, you're attempting to read an object of one type as another which is not allowed (unless you're reading as an `unsigned char`).  There could be further issues if the pointer value you create is not properly aligned for its type.

Then there is also the issue of endianness.  Bytes sent over a network are typically sent in big-endian format, i.e. most significant byte first.  If your system is little-endian, it will interpret the bytes in the reverse order.

The function you posted demonstrates the proper way of deserializing an `unsigned long` from a byte buffer in a standard compliant manner.

Comment: I'm on a little-endian system. So when we do (unsigned long int)buf[0] << 24, we just assume that the buf points to a valid memory and we interpret it is as if it were pointing to an 8 byte long integer? (unsigned long int is 8 byte on my system).

Comment: That piece of code doesn't depend on endianness.  It takes the byte at `buf[0]`, casts it to an `unsigned long`, then performs a left shift.

Comment: How can you move 24 bit places in a byte. Wouldn't that just be wrong?

Comment: @Shadowmeth That's why the value is cast to an `unsigned long`.  It makes it at least a 32 bit value.

Comment: So let me know if I am correct. Although its a byte by typecasting we tell the compiler to treat it as an integer and bit shift (we are creating an anonymus int here right?)

Comment: @Shadowmeth The cast gives us an expression of type `unsigned long`.  That value is shifted, and the result of that expression is also of type `unsigned long`.  That is further bitwise OR'ed with two more `unsigned long` expressions and `unsigned char` value which is first converted to `unsigned long` to match the other operand.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks. Also the compiler will implicitly cast buf[3] to unsigned int too right?

Comment: @Shadowmeth Not to `unsigned int` but to `unsigned long` to match the type of the other operand to `|`.  And this is actually called a conversion, not a cast.

Comment: @Shadowmeth Also, feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: I understand it. Thanks for your time. I just learned a new thing about typecasting. I always thought of it as just changing the types but didn't know how compilers actually interpreted typecasts.

Answer (score 0):

That would make it dependable on the endianness of the platform. So we pick out the parts from the defined order to make it platform neutral.

Answer (score 0):

`buf[0]` is treated as 8 bit unsigned value. If we do this:

`(unsigned long int)buf[0] << 24`, by casting we tell to treat it not as 8 bit value, but as 64 bit so we got more space to work with.

We shifted only `buf[0]`, `buf[1]` and other fields are not considered during shifting process.

If you want to convert to `unsigned long` lets say a string `"aabbccd"` and we don't care about endianness we can do this like below:

```
char* str = const_cast<char *>("aabbccd\0");
unsigned long value = *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned long *>(str));
std::cout << value << std::endl;
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<char *>(&value) << std::endl;
```

It should be pointed, `unsigned long` can store up to 8 chars only, because its 64 bit integer.
However if many platforms are going to use same data, doing it like this maybe be not enough due to endianness. The approach given in your book is as someone mentioned platform neutral.

Comment: Why are you hardcoding an additional null-terminator in your string literals? Why are you stripping `const`?

Comment: `unsigned long` may not be 64 bits; that depends on your platform and toolchain.

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour. Though it is legal to reinterpret a sequence of bytes as an `unsigned long`, _it actually has to have started life as an `unsigned long`_. You can't just feed it random bytes.

Answer (score 0):

> The function expects a `char *` pointer but it dereferences the
>   pointer and casts it to a (`unsigned long int`) and perform some
>   bitwise operations.

Actually, what the code does is use the array index operator to pull out the first *byte* from the buffer, casts that to an `unsigned long int`, and *then* does some bitwise operations. The pointer that's dereferenced is an `unsigned char *` not anything to do with long integers.

> Why couldn't we just pass it as a  (unsigned int *) instead of
>   (unsigned char *).

Because it isn't a pointer to any kind of integer. It's a pointer to a buffer of `unsigned char`, i.e. bytes. Treating a pointer as if it were a pointer to a different type is likely to lead to a violation of the "Strict Aliasing Rule" (which I encourage you to read about).

> Also if the parameter was replaced by (void *) and then inside code we
>   did some thing like `*(unsigned long int *)buf[0] << 24` will we get
>   the same result?

No. If you define `buf` as a `void*`, then `buf[0]` is a meaningless expression. If `buf` is defined as, or cast to, an `unsigned long int *`, then `buf[0]` is an `unsigned long int`, not the `unsigned char` that the algorithm is expecting. There will almost certainly be too many bits set (as many as 64, not 8) and the result of the expression will be invalid.